# Magento 2 - Change theme for product to "Magento Blank" not working - invalid template file

Tags: magento2, product, theme, design

I try to change the theme for a product to the default Magento Blank theme. But I get this error:

```
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\ValidatorException): Invalid template file: 'Company_Base::header/mobile/icons/search.phtml' in module: '' block's name: 'mobile-search'
```

The file **Company_Base::header/mobile/icons/search.phtml** is from my custom theme. It is defined here `app/design/frontend/company/fresh/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml`.

Why does it even try to load a template from my custom theme if I want to load the Magento Blank theme?

Why do I get this error?

I already tried to recompile everything and clear cache, does not help.

Tested in Magento 2.4.2

---

If I change the theme globally to Magento Blank then I also get errors. But they dissapear after I disable all third party modules and enable them one by one compiling at each step.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you declear block 'mobile-search' with template Company_Base::header/mobile/icons/search.phtml in your **module**, so it will load for all themes, but the problem here is the file does not exist in `app/code/Company/Base/view/frontend/templates/header/mobile/icons/search.phtml`.

Comment: No, the only occurence of search.phtml is in the theme. I searched the whole codebase for `search.phtml` and this is the only thing it found, besides some other search.phtml from the core

Comment: I still would like to check if you declare block **mobile-search** with template Company_Base::header/mobile/icons/search.phtml in your module or not (in case you declare block in layout XML in module and put the phtml file in your custom theme). Could you please run `grep -r mobile-search app/code` to get results?

Comment: If you don't get any results with the command above, let's remove `var/view_preprocessed/pub/static/frontend/` and  `pub/static/frontend` folders before running the deploy static content command. The clear cache and go to the frontend page to check the result.

Comment: If the issue still persists, try to **temporary** remove `<your custom theme>/Company_Base/templates/header/mobile/icons/search.phtml` and related layout xml file. Then remove `var/view_preprocessed/pub/static/frontend/` and `pub/static/frontend` folders before running the deploy static content command. Then clear cache and go to the frontend page to check the result.

Comment: 1. It is defined here `app/design/frontend/hausfux/fresh/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml`

Comment: 2. I deleted the files in these folders and redeployed static files, but the error is still there.

Comment: 3. Not helpful either.